# How to correctly refactor this big and with very similar code if/else statements?

Tags: c#, if-statement, refactoring

I'm trying to refactor this code that would be much more bigger and I'm wondering which is the better way to do it.

```
string obje = String.Empty;
long userId = 0;
long objNewId = 0;
long objOldId = 0;
string action = String.Empty;

if (oldObject.GetType() == typeof(FooDto))
{
    obje = ConstantParams.WCFLOG_APPLICATION_Foo;
    FooDto newFoo = (FooDto)response.Data;
    FooDto oldFoo = (FooDto)oldObject;

    userId = newFoo.UserApplicationId;
    objNewId = newFoo.Id;
    objOldId = oldFoo.Id;
}
else if (oldObject.GetType() == typeof(BarDto))
{
    obje = ConstantParams.WCFLOG_APPLICATION_Bar;
    BarDto newBar = (BarDto)response.Data;
    BarDto oldBar = (BarDto)oldObject;

    userId = newBar.UserApplicationId;
    objNewId = newBar.Id;
    objOldId = oldBar.Id;
}

action = (objOldId == 0) ? ConstantParams.WCFLOG_APPLICATION_NEW : ConstantParams.WCFLOG_APPLICATION_UPD;

string message = Helper.GenerateMessage(action, obje, userId, objNewId);
```

The thing is that it may be possible to write something like this but I don't know if something like that is possible:

```
obje = ConstantParams.WCFLOG_APPLICATION_[[XXX]];
[[XXX]]Dto newItem = ([[XXX]]Dto)response.Data;
[[XXX]]Dto oldItem = ([[XXX]]Dto)oldObject;

userId = newItem .UserApplicationId;
objNewId = newItem .Id;
objOldId = oldItem .Id;
```

Comment: questions about refactoring working code are often better asked on [codereview.se]

Comment: Minor - but just so you understand others and so you are better understood by others: the verb is "refactor", not "refactorize".  I will correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming Foo, Bar, and their counterparts all inherit from or implement a common class which holds Id and UserApplicationId - let's call it SuperclassDto because you don't specify, this can be as simple as:

```
string obje = String.Empty;
long userId = 0;
long objNewId = 0;
long objOldId = 0;
string action = String.Empty;

obje = ConstantParams.WCFLOG_APPLICATION_Foo;

SuperclassDto newDto = (SuperclassDto)response.Data;
SuperclassDto oldDto = (SuperclassDto)oldObject;

userId = newFoo.UserApplicationId;
objNewId = newDto.Id;
objOldId = oldDto.Id;

action = (objOldId == 0) ? ConstantParams.WCFLOG_APPLICATION_NEW : ConstantParams.WCFLOG_APPLICATION_UPD;

string message = Helper.GenerateMessage(action, obje, userId, objNewId);
```

If your inheritance/implementation hierarchy isn't this simple, you should be able to coerce into such a state.

Comment: That's a nice option, but that will leave me with the if/else too when using the `ConstantParams.xxx` and it could be big.

Comment: Ah.  Now I see.  OK, so add a getThing() method to SuperclassDto, and in each subclass implement to return the appropriate Thing - or initialize it.  Or build a map from class to Thing.  Foo, for instance, would return WCFLOG_APPLICATION_Foo.  Or the map would be from Foo class to WCFLOG_APPLICATION_Foo.